# Is empirical Bayes an iterative scheme?

Tags: empirical-bayes

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_Bayes_method#Introduction) article on the empirical Bayes method (emphasis mine):

> In, for example, a two-stage hierarchical Bayes model, observed data $y=\{y_{1},y_{2},\dots ,y_{n}\}$ are assumed to be generated from an unobserved set of parameters $\theta =\{\theta _{1},\theta _{2},\dots ,\theta _{n}\}$ according to a probability distribution $p(y \mid \theta)$. In turn, the parameters $\theta$ can be considered samples drawn from a population characterised by hyperparameters $\eta$, according to a probability distribution $p(\theta \mid \eta )$. **In the hierarchical Bayes model, though not in the empirical Bayes approximation, the hyperparameters $\eta$, are considered to be drawn from an unparameterized distribution $p(\eta )$.**

However, later in the article, it is written that

> Alternatively, the expression can be written as
> $$
> p(\theta \mid y)=\int p(\theta \mid \eta ,y)p(\eta \mid y)\;d\eta =\int {\frac {p(y\mid \theta )p(\theta \mid \eta )}{p(y\mid \eta )}}p(\eta \mid y)\;d\eta
> $$
> and the term in the integral can in turn be expressed as
> $$
> p(\eta \mid y)=\int p(\eta \mid \theta )p(\theta \mid y)\;d\theta
> $$
> These suggest an iterative scheme, qualitatively similar in structure to a [Gibbs sampler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling), to evolve successively improved approximations to $p(\theta \mid y)$ and $p(\eta \mid y)$. First, calculate an initial approximation to $p(\theta \mid y)$ ignoring the $\eta$ dependence completely; then calculate an approximation to $p(\eta \mid y)$ based upon the initial approximate distribution of $p(\theta \mid y)$; then use this $p(\eta \mid y)$ to update the approximation for $p(\theta \mid y)$; then update $p(\eta \mid y)$; and so on.

My questions are:

1. If $\eta$ is **not** considered be drawn from an unparameterized distribution $p(\eta)$ in the empirical Bayes method, then how/why is it treated as a random variable in the expressions above for $p(\theta \mid y)$ and $p(\eta \mid y)$?
2. Earlier in the article, it is written that

> Using Bayes' theorem,
> $$
> p(\theta \mid y)={\frac {p(y\mid \theta )p(\theta )}{p(y)}}={\frac {p(y\mid \theta )}{p(y)}}\int p(\theta \mid \eta )p(\eta )\,d\eta
> $$
> In general, this integral will not be tractable analytically or symbolically and must be evaluated by numerical methods.

However, I do not see how the integrals in the expressions above for $p(\theta \mid y)$ and $p(\eta \mid y)$ are any more tractable.

3. The article does not specify how $p(y \mid \theta),p(\theta \mid \eta),p(y \mid \eta),$ and $p(\eta \mid \theta)$ are computed. How are they computed in the empirical Bayes method?
4. It is my understanding that the empirical Bayes method essentially involves estimating the (non-random) parameter $\eta$ for the prior on $\theta$ using some samples of $\theta$. Intuitively, I would assume that this would be done once using maximum likelihood estimation, as was done in the book [Introduction to Empirical Bayes: Examples from Baseball Statistics](https://drob.gumroad.com/l/empirical-bayes) by David Robinson. However, in this case, we are not given samples of $\theta$, but we are instead given samples of $y$. How is this dealt with?

---

**Update**

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator#Empirical_Bayes_estimators) is an example of an empirical Bayes estimator that more closely fits my understanding. It is part of the [Bayes estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator) Wikipedia entry.

Comment: (+1) for this question and also to @Xi'an's answer. I've read this part of wiki as well as looked at some of the original references on empirical Bayes. Until now, I've never been able to reconcile my understanding of the problematic part in wiki and from the references, so it's good to know that others find it puzzling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is correct that, in [the (parametric) empirical Bayes approach](https://amzn.to/3y8uswY), the hyperparameter is estimated from the data $y$, by $\hat\eta(y)$, replacing the prior $p(\theta \mid \eta ,y)$ with the empirical "prior" $p(\theta \mid \hat\eta(y) ,y)$ and failing to account for the plugged-in $\hat\eta(y)$. There is therefore no prior distribution on $\eta$ involved in this setting.

The following paragraph in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_Bayes_method#Introduction) is thus puzzling to me as well, as it assumes the existence of an [hyperprior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperprior) $p(\eta)$. It would be more appropriate for the hierarchical Bayes article. In this setting, since
$$p(\theta \mid y)=\int p(\theta \mid \eta ,y)p(\eta \mid y)\;d\eta =\int {\frac {p(y\mid \theta )p(\theta \mid \eta )}{p(y\mid \eta )}}p(\eta \mid y)\;d\eta$$
one can rewrite
$$p(\theta \mid y)=\mathbb E_{\eta|y}\left[\frac {p(y\mid \theta )p(\theta \mid \eta )}{p(y\mid \eta )}\right]$$
and, similarly,
$$p(\eta \mid y)=\mathbb E_{\theta|y}\left[p(\eta|\theta)\right]$$
The numerical approximation would then start from a sample
$$\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_T\sim \pi(\theta|\hat\eta(y),y)$$
then generate
$$\eta_1,\ldots,\eta_T\sim \hat\pi(\eta|y)\propto\sum_{t=1}^T p(\eta|\theta_t)$$
then redraw a new sample
$$\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_T\sim \hat\pi(\theta|y) \propto\sum_{t=1}^T p(y\mid \theta )p(\theta \mid \eta^t )$$
until some stability is achieved in the samples.

This is however a rewording of the Gibbs sampler (which is the special case when $T=1$). The method is thus exact sampling from the hierarchical posterior and unrelated with empirical Bayes, as far as I understand.

Using the alternative representation
$$p(\theta \mid y)={\frac {p(y\mid \theta )p(\theta )}{p(y)}}={\frac {p(y\mid \theta )}{p(y)}}\int p(\theta \mid \eta )p(\eta )\,d\eta$$
makes little sense as well if using the implementation:

- generate $$\eta_1,\ldots,\eta_T\sim p(\eta)$$
- generate $$\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_T\sim \hat\pi(\theta|y) \propto p(y|\theta) \sum_{t=1}^T p(\theta|\eta_t)$$

which is not a particularly recommended approximation (as the $\eta_t$'s are simulated from the prior).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A few follow-up questions: 1) Assuming that $\eta$ does not have a prior, using an empirical Bayes method, is it possible to estimate $\eta$ using samples of $y$ instead of samples of $\theta$? 2) Is there any context where empirical Bayes becomes an iterative method? So far, I have only seen literature where $\eta$ is estimated once. 3) Any good references to understand Gibbs sampling in more detail?

Comment: Definitely, Empirical Bayes uses the data $y$ to estimate $\eta$, based on $p(y\eta)$, not a sample of $\theta$'s. There is no sample of $\theta$'s to consider since the issue is to estimate $\theta$.

Comment: Do you know of good references that discuss this estimation procedure in more detail? So far, I have only found references that discuss estimating $\eta$ using samples of $\theta$ and not samples of $y$.

Comment: Any Bayesian textbook (Carlin & Louis, mine) containing an entry on empirical Bayesian methods will cover the same idea that the hyperparameter $\eta$ is estimated based on the data $y$, using $p(y|\eta)$ or an approximation as the likelihood. I do not understand how one could use "samples of $\theta$" in this empirical Bayes context.

Comment: My confusion stems from the fact that I was initially assuming that $y$ and $\theta$ do not share $\eta$ as a parameter. I've asked about this in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538837/is-a-common-cause-relationship-required-to-perform-empirical-bayes-estimation). I know you may not have the time, but I would appreciate your feedback on that question.