# Is empirical Bayes estimation still possible without common parameters?

Tags: empirical-bayes

In [An Introduction to Empirical Bayes Data Analysis](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2682801) by George Casella (1985), it is given that
\begin{align}
X|\theta &\sim N(\theta,\sigma^2) \\
\theta &\sim N(\mu,\tau^2) \\
\theta|X &\sim N\left(\frac{\theta\tau^2 + \mu\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+\tau^2},\frac{\sigma^2\tau^2}{\sigma^2 + \tau^2}\right) \\
X &\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2 + \tau^2)
\end{align}

It is my understanding that empirical Bayes estimation involves estimating the parameters $\mu$ and $\tau$ that $p(\theta)$ depends on using the samples $\mathcal{D} = \{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N\}$ obtained from $p(x)$.

Using the law of total expectation,
\begin{align}
E[X] &= E_{p(\theta)}[E[X\mid\theta]] \\
&= E_{p(\theta)}[\theta] \\
&= \mu
\end{align}
and using the law of total variance,
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(X) &= E_{p(\theta)}[Var(X\mid\theta)] + \text{Var}(E[X\mid\theta]) \\
&= E_{p(\theta)}[\sigma^2] + \text{Var}(\theta) \\
&= \sigma^2 + \tau^2
\end{align}
Now suppose that we compute the sample mean and variance of $X$ from $\mathcal{D}$ such that
\begin{align}
\hat{\mu}_\mathcal{D} &\approx E[X] \\
\hat{\sigma}^2_\mathcal{D} &\approx \text{Var}(X)
\end{align}
Substituting these estimates into the equations above yields
\begin{align}
\mu &\approx \hat{\mu}_\mathcal{D} \\
\sigma^2 + \tau^2 &\approx \hat{\sigma}^2_\mathcal{D}
\end{align}
Re-arranging the second expression yields
\begin{align}
\mu &\approx \hat{\mu}_\mathcal{D} \\
\tau^2 &\approx \hat{\sigma}^2_\mathcal{D} - \sigma^2
\end{align}
which are the empirical Bayes estimates of the parameters $\mu$ and $\tau^2$ that we are looking for. This, by the way, is a special case of the [method of moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)).

Since
\begin{align}
X &\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2 + \tau^2) \\
\theta &\sim N(\mu,\tau^2)
\end{align}
I can see that empirical Bayes estimation was only possible when **both** $X$ and $\theta$ are dependent on $\mu$ and $\tau$. Moreover, an estimate of $\mu$ using the sample mean of $\mathcal{D}$ and an estimate of $\sigma^2 + \tau^2$ using the sample variance of $\mathcal{D}$ will yield information about $\mu$ and $\tau$, which are the parameters of $p(\theta)$.

However, is empirical Bayes estimation still possible if $X$ and $\theta$ are **not** dependent on the same parameters? For example, suppose that
$$
\begin{align}
X &\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2) \\
\theta &\sim N(\tau,\eta^2)
\end{align}
$$
Would empirical Bayes estimation still be possible in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion stems from considering marginals rather than joint. When $X$ depends on $\theta$ and $\theta$ depends on $\eta$ then marginally $X$ depends on $\eta$, which makes empirical Bayesian estimation feasible.

To consider that
\begin{align}
X &\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2) \\
\theta &\sim N(\tau,\eta^2)
\end{align}
means that $X$ does not depend on $\theta$ hence that $\theta$ cannot be estimated based on the observation of $X$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! So what you are saying is that since $$p(x) = \int p(x|\theta)p(\theta) \ \text{d}\theta$$ then if $p(\theta) = p(\theta;\eta)$, then $p(x) = p(x;\eta)$, right?

Comment: Yes, this is straightforward, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Last question: are the laws of total expectation and variance always used when performing empirical Bayes estimation, or is it only used in this special case?

Comment: Actually, what I think I meant was: is the method of moments always used when performing empirical Bayes estimation? Since using the laws of total expectation and variance as done above is an application of the method of moments?

Comment: Any method for estimating $\eta$ is acceptable as empirical Bayes estimator. Even a Bayesian estimator would work.

Comment: Given that we don't observe samples of $\theta$, then is it still possible to use maximum likelihood estimation? If so, how?

Comment: This is the whole point of empirical Bayes estimation: $\eta$ is estimated by $\hat\eta(x)$ based on $p(x|\eta)$ and then $\theta$ by $\hat\theta(x)$ based on $p(\theta|x,\hat\eta(x))$.